# Getting error while using SPOOL with APPEND

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

I am using SQLPLUS version `DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1102000200" (CHAR)`. In which i am trying to `spool` a file which is already exist with `append` command. But it's giving me an error as

`SQL> spool test_dir/test.txt append;
SP2-0556: Invalid file name.`

can any one please help me why am i getting this error

Answer (score 0):

`Spool` is a client side utility and generates the file at same location or from where you are executing the script or location from where your sqlplus is started or at path specified by you. **not in oracle server directory.**

Now, in your you case specify the whole path then it will work.

Something like:

```
Spool c:\windows\temp\test.txt
```

Cheers!!

Comment: The mentioned directory is full path for the file. Not sure why i am getting the error even after mentioning the full path. Also the same path works fine with out APPEND :-(e

Comment: **The mentioned directory is full path for the file.** means?? is `test_dir` a directory?

Comment: Yes, it is the directory.

Comment: I mean oracle directory?

Comment: Yes, oracle directory